# ZF2 set global function for whole application

Tags: php, function, zend-framework, zend-framework2, global

For my application I have written a function which convert strings into SEO proof slug's/urls. I am using the function in different modules but for now I define the function over and over again in the controller or in a database model.

I am wondering how it is possible to set this function just once and use it in the whole application (in the right way).

Thanks you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a service, but don't use a closure.  Closures don't cache.

**module.config.php**

```
use Application\Service\SeoService;
use Application\Factory\Service\SeoService;

//...

    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            SeoService::class => SeoServiceFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Then write your SeoService factory and your SeoService class:

**Factory**

```
namespace Application\Factory\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;    
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Application\Service\SeoService;

class SeoServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $service = new SeoService( /* dependencies */ );
        return $service;           
    }
}
```

Then write your service

**Service**

```
namespace Application\Service\SeoService;

class SeoService
{

    public function __construct( /* dependencies */ ){

    }

    public function convertString( $url ){
        // do your thing here
    }
}
```

So then in your controllers, you will just:

```
use Application\Service\SeoService;

$seo = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( SeoService::class );
$seo->convertString( ... );
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[Zend Plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html) can assist you with this.

There are some good articles on how to create a custom plugin out there, [here](http://lab.empirio.no/custom-controller-plugin-in-zf2.html) is one to begin with :)

Basically you need take the following 3 steps:

1. Create a plugin class extending `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin`
2. Include your plugin into the 'invokables' controller's plugins list
3. Call and use your plugin within your controller like any other build-in ZF2 controller

Comment: What about using controller plugin in model?

Comment: Controller plugins are only good for the controller, hence the naming :) I'm not in favour to put too much logic in the data models but if you have to, one way would be embedding such functionality as part of your abstraction.

Comment: So in my opinion best way is to use Traits.

Comment: Another reasonable approach :) but again totally depend on the main design and how important is to add a convertor to your data model. and how frequently you need to use such function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right way to do this, because you should use ZFs built in Plugin and DI System.

But you could achieve what you want by adding this function in your `index.php`.

---

**Warning, not tested:**

Also you should be able to add this as Factory to ServiceManager:

```php
// in module.config.php
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'somefunction' => function(){
            return function($param){
                return $param;
            };
        }
    )
)
```

```php
// from service-manager
$fn = $sm->get('somefunction');
$fn('param');
```

Answer (score 0):

I see many valid approaches for this.

1. You could define class something like `Tools` and in this class define your function as static method. In future you can define more similar functions in this class. And call wherever you want `Tools::makeSlug();`
2. Another approach is to define trait with this function and extends every class where you want to use function from this trait, one of them could be your `makeSlug()` function.

Comment: Yea, using static methods is another possible approach. this might be a good choice for small tasks such as converting strings (as you need here). but for more complex tasks i would recommend using plugins :)